# Unable to resolve ILogger from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core, ilogger

I've configured my console application's `Main` like so

```cs
var services = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddLogging(logging => logging.AddConsole())
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```

And then I try to use it in another class like so

```cs
private readonly ILogger _logger;
    
public MyClass(ILogger logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

public void MyFunc()
{
    _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "My Message");
}
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger'

I've tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51329388/2025666) but it didn't work for me.

**Edit**
Based on Yaakov's comment below and [this Github comment](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/92#issuecomment-223991293) I'm able to resolve it correctly by doing this

```cs
public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}
```

I would have preferred to have this in the initial `BuildServiceProvider` but looks like I'm gonna have to repeat this every time I want to use the logger (or create my own ILogger).

Comment: So where is the part you register your servicecollection?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü I don't think I'm doing that separately. I've got other resolvers in that chain after `..AddLogging(logging => logging.AddConsole())` like `.AddScoped<IMyInterface, MyMethod>()` which resolves correctly.

Comment: If you do not register your `new ServiceCollection()` with your application, it does not work

Comment: Does it work if you try resolve an `ILogger<MyClass>`?

Comment: @yaakov Yes, it does actually. But is there another way to register it so that I don't have to do `public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger)` every time?

Comment: Not that I know of. I believe it's designed that way for DI to also add information about where the data was logged from.

Comment: This is a problem, although maybe a small one. `ILogger<T>` is an empty interface which inherits from `ILogger`. It represents an implementation detail, so classes should not have to depend on it. Why should my class know whether my logging is separated by category? This is even shown in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#create-logs), where the constructor requires `ILogger<AboutModel>` and then assigns it to a field of type `ILogger`. That's not right.

Comment: My answer covers this - use `LoggerFactory`

Answer (score 209, accepted):

`ILogger` is no longer registered by default but `ILogger<T>` is. If you still want to use ILogger you can register it manually with the following (in `Startup.cs`):

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<AnyClass>>();
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger), logger);
    ...
}
```

Where `AnyClass` can be something generic, such as:

```cs
public class ApplicationLogs
{
}
```

So:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<ApplicationLog>>();
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger), logger);
    ...
}
```

`ILogger` will now resolve via constructor injection.

Comment: This is considered bad practice (building your service provider from ConfigureServices). This way, all your singleton services are instantiated twice.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen Including or indicating the preferred implementation would have been helpful.

Comment: Pretty sure you should register a transient that resolves `ILogger<ApplicationLog>` at runtime

Comment: The creation of an intermediate service provider is a bit shady, but this could be a solution to avoid it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70610564/646942

Comment: To avoid double instantiation of services you can register ILogger service in next way
services.AddTransient<ILogger>(s => s.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>());

Answer (score 35):

I am assuming you are using the default template for .net core web application.
In your your Startup.cs you should have a method like this↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        //Do the service register here and extra stuff you want
         services.AddLogging(config =>
        {
            config.AddDebug();
            config.AddConsole();
            //etc
        });

    }
```

Edit: I have written a simple program for you to show how it works

```
public class MyClass
{

    private readonly ILogger<MyClass> _logger;


    public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public void MyFunc()
    {
        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "My Message");
    }
}



public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection().AddLogging(logging => logging.AddConsole());
        services.AddSingleton<MyClass>();//Singleton or transient?!
        var s = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var myclass = s.GetService<MyClass>();
     }
}
```

[image]
Edit: Output of the program:
[image]

Comment: It's a console application, like the question says. What you've shown in `services.AddLogging`, how's that different from what I've got in the question?

Comment: Let me ask again.`var services = new ServiceCollection()` you have created a new servicecollection right? where did you register that to your application? What does resolve the dependancy? Who creates the new instance of MyClass

Comment: Well, man since you refuse the help :) there is nothing more I can do than suggest reading upon DI

Comment: Sorry, is that how it's supposed to work or supposed to _not work_?

Comment: This shows how it is supposed to work, as you can see in the example code that it works and logger is a ConsoleLogger. I do not understand why we can not understand each other :(

Comment: @jeevs, I also added the output of the program as well.

Comment: The question was how to use  MyClass(ILogger logger), your answer is how to use  MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim, Thanks for the heads up on a question that is 2 years old :)

Answer (score 25):

For .NET Core 3.1, be sure to include the

`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`

package and configure logging by calling

```
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddLogging();
```

Comment: THIS is the real answer I was looking for... <3
Working on custom ServiceProvider on WPF Core like a charm.

Comment: This doesn't work in .Net 6.0

Answer (score 24):

For anyone that gets this error using NLog, I found I was making the following error in my dependency injection:

```
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public ErrorController(ILogger ilogger)
        {
            _logger = ilogger;
        }
```

[According to the documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-5), in .Net 5, you need to add a type of the Controller itself to the logger in order to avoid this issue. Dependency injecting as such fixed the error:

```
        private readonly ILogger<ErrorController> _logger;

        public ErrorController(ILogger<ErrorController> ilogger)
        {
            _logger = ilogger;
        }
```

After making the above change, this fixed my issue. DO NOT ATTEMPT ANY OF THE SOLUTIONS HERE! This will only send you down a rabbit hole.

Hope this helps anyone in the future!

Answer (score 19):

In .NET Core, `ILogger<T>` is automatically registered for you.  As `ILogger<T>` inherits from `ILogger`, you can request an instance of `ILogger<T>` from the `IServiceProvider`.

For example:
`services.AddSingleton<ILogger>(svc => svc.GetRequiredService<ILogger<MyClassType>>());`

Note that this will return an `ILogger<MyClassType>` wherever you've got a non-generic `ILogger` constructor parameter so if you need more than one, look into creating it specifically for that instance by using the `AddSingleton` (or transient/or scoped) implementationFactory override.

Answer (score 17):

As noted in a comment, the accepted answer has the problem that `BuildServiceProvider` should not be used in `ConfigureServices`, since it creates another copy of each singleton (in fact, of the whole DI container). Here is an alternative one-liner that avoids that problem. In `ConfigureServices`, add the line

```
services.AddSingleton<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger>(provider => 
   provider.GetRequiredService<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<AnyClass>>());
```

where `AnyClass` can be any class, as explained in the accepted answer. This redirects the resolution of `ILogger` to that of `ILogger<AnyClass>`.

Like the accepted answer, this one has the disadvantage that Serilog's `SourceContext` will be set to `AnyClass`. So, if your Serilog configuration contains an `outputTemplate` that contains `{SourceContext}`, your log will show `AnyClass` instead of the class that contains the logging statement.

Comment: This is a great approach. Sleek and clean.

Comment: This worked for me in a rather unique worst case scenario (winforms with a host builder)

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer (as provided by @sam-shiles) goes in the right direction. I don't like that it requires building an intermediate service provider, and the registration of a singleton instance is maybe not wanted as well.

So, I suggest the registration of a factory instead, that utilizes `ILoggerFactory`. The creation of an empty class (like `AnyClass` is also not needed).

```cs
...
services.AddTransient(provider =>
{
    var loggerFactory = provider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
    const string categoryName = "Any";
    return loggerFactory.CreateLogger(categoryName);
});
...
```

Answer (score 6):

This answer isn't necessarily for .net Core or whatever dependency injection is being used by the poster. I ran across this searching for a way to fix this error using Autofac in an asp.net forms web application. The answer of logging not being "registered by default" led me to add this to my registrations:

```
builder.RegisterType<LoggerFactory>().As<ILoggerFactory>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Logger<>)).As(typeof(ILogger<>)).SingleInstance();
```

And now it works for me. This is the second time I searched for this answer and ended up here, I forgot how I fixed it the first time. So I thought I'd post my answer.

Comment: You Save me! :-)

Answer (score 4):

The approach I used when trying to use an `ILogger` (Because it's no longer injected), as to inject a `ILoggerFactory`, and then when your code wants a specific logger (say its some custom factory you're `new`ing up, `LoggerFactory.CreateLogger("Logger Name")` - Below

But for your case,it looks like you want a `ILogger<MyClass>`

```
public class MyClass
{

    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;


    public MyClass(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _loggerFactory = _loggerFactory;
    }
    public void MyFunc()
    {
       new MyNewThatsASpecialCase(_loggerFactory.CreateLogger("MyNewThatsASpecialCase"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me as LoggerFactory was the only instance available at the time I was requesting the service and not the class loggers.

Comment: This syntax is a bit more refactoring-friendly
LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyClass>();

Comment: I did say in my answer, there are two options Logger<T> or "MySpecialCaseLogger"

Answer (score 4):

Based on @[Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680563/barry-franklin) answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64744036/959779) found out how to register generic log provider for `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection()
                            .AddLogging(logging => logging.AddConsole())
                            .BuildServiceProvider();

services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>()
services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Describe(typeof(ILogger<>),typeof(Logger<>),ServiceLifetime.Scoped))
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me to get DI working for ILogger.

For .NET Core see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Specifically:

```
.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddConsole();
            })
```

Reference:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.AddConsole();
    })
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

Comment: net 6.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0