# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Logging at Startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

In ASP.NET Core 2.2 I used to be able to log exception errors in startup by using DI, but now on 3.1

```
   public class Startup
   {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Startup> logger)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        private readonly ILogger<Startup> _logger;
        ....
```

but now an exception appears when I run my app:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[TestProject.Startup]' while attempting to activate 'TestProject.Startup'.

My logging is configured for the ones who are asking in the Program

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.File(@"Logging\log.txt",
               fileSizeLimitBytes: 10_000,
               rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
               shared: true,
               flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Starting up");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
            }
            finally

            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution in this thread and my problem is solved:

[How do I write logs from within Startup.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287648/how-do-i-write-logs-from-within-startup-cs)

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921966/unable-to-resolve-ilogger-from-microsoft-extensions-logging solve your issue?

Comment: The obvious reason is that your code hasn't configured either logging or DI yet. Those methods are part of the `Startup` class and are called *after* the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, i have found the solution and i edited my post with more details and the solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write logs from within Startup.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287648/how-do-i-write-logs-from-within-startup-cs)

Comment: @MaximilianAst check my post at the end, i posted the solution

Comment: Yea there I copied it from, When you flag a question as duplicate it posts this comment automatically